# How to show different fields to user than what we have in a custom object?

Tags: apex, visualforce

i have a custom object `test__c` with name and DOB fields.I want to show 4 fields name ,month,day,year for user to enter data and on save button click i want to concatenate month,day,year to save as DOB in test__C.I want user to enter 5 rows of data at a time.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please make sure to include the relevant portions of your code, along with the specific issue you are struggling with and the complete text and location of any errors, in the body of your question. See [ask] for more about our expectations, and please [edit] your question to add information rather than posting comments.

Answer (score 0):

You could override the detail and edit pages of your custom object to display a concatenated version of values from multiple fields on the object as one string in the format of: month + '/' + day + '/' + year

[This documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_tabs.htm) goes over the basics of doing that, but code will need to be specific to your particular implementation requirements.

Comment: Thank you so much for quick reply ..here is my scenario,my object has Name, DOB field but user wants to see Name,month,day and year and also user has to see empty table with 5 rows to insert data.on hitting SAVE button i have t process data and insert into the object.please help me.

Comment: Are you able to post any code that you've already attempted this with? Is there a specific error that's blocking you?